# How do I skin an Adobe Flash Player Settings pop up and is it even possible?

Tags: apache-flex, adobe, flash, skinning

I am trying to create a professional chat application using Flex.  Unfortunately, the security window that pops up asking the user to allow or deny the application access to the web cam, (the Adobe Flash Player Settings Window) doesn't really look that great and I'd like to be able to skin it.

I'd really love to make this window look nicer.  Is it even possible to skin this window?

Comment: I tried to do this with the print dialog once, and concluded that it was not possible. Unfortunately I wouldn't be surprised if that is also true here :(

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to skin the security settings popup.

You'll just have to make do with the default.

Answer (score 0):

Also, remember that if for any reason your Flash movie is smaller in size than the popup itself, it won't show up and just silently deny (safest for the user).

I learnt that the hard way : )